# What method can I use to calculate the temperature within a house being cooled by vents on the floor?

Tags: heat-transfer

[image]To simplify the problem, if we just imagine a rectangle resting vertically, and on the bottom face (the one closer to the 'ground') there are slits on that face. On the opposite face to that (the one closer to the 'sky'), there are also slits. In this case I am assuming no q in or out through the other 4 faces. The reason I put 'ground'  in quotes, is because I am imagining the rectangle is not actually resting on the ground, but is instead raised off the ground through some mechanism that doesn't affect heat transfer or fluid flow of the air. Also assume the are is some T1 below the bottom face, and T2 above the top face. T2>T1.

My question is how I would go about calculating the temperature gradient within the house? The aim is to see if this is a viable way of cooling. To be clear, I am not asking for someone to work this out in detail, but rather an approach to the problem.

I spoke with a professor and he suggested using density differences to calculate the fluid flow, but I do not know how to get a temperature gradient from that information. Thank you.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with a sketch of what you mean?

Comment: Hi Wasabi sure, I am uploading one now.

Comment: If the ceiling vent is intended to be an exhaust vent and there's no back pressure.... **and** you've got a fan pumping the cold air into the room, the temperature in the entire volume will be close to uniform, save perhaps for the corners.

Comment: There wasn't meant to be a fan; I realise this would be a very impractical cooling solution. However, I am curious as to how you would calculate that, or how you would determine the temperature distribution. Would it just be empirical testing?